Different numbers in all cells of a 3x3 board v2
You are given a 3x3 grid filled with zeroes:

Each turn you can select a 2x2 sub-grid of adjacent cells and increase each of its numbers by 1. Is it possible to obtain different numbers in each cell? Bonus: what is the least number of turns needed to achieve this?

I believe the minimum number of increments is

 12 increments


 

To show this to be the minimum, let's first note that

 every 2x2 square must be incremented at least once. We can prove this by assuming the contrary: let's pick a corner, say, the top left:      Consider the two squares in red. Without incrementing the top left, the only way to increase either of them is to increment the top right- which will increment both of them. Therefore, the two red squares will be identical as long as the top left is not incremented.

We also know that

 each corner must be incremented a different number of times, since otherwise they would be identical.

So now that we know these two things, we know that

 the minimum number of increments is 10 (1+2+3+4). However, it's clear that 10 increments isn't possible. The 1-corner must be adjacent to either the 2-corner (which will create a 3 in between them that overlaps with the 3-corner) or the 3-corner (which will create a 4 in between them that overlaps with the 4-corner.)


 The only combination of viable numbers that can reach 11 increments is 1, 2, 3, 5. However, in this case, 2 and 3 must be diagonally adjacent from each other (or they'd create a 5 in between them.) However, 1 and 2 must also be diagonally adjacent from each other (or they create a 3 in between them.) This is obviously impossible.


 Let's look at 12. There are 2 possible sets of increments that could work for 12: 1, 2, 4, 5 and 1, 2, 3, 6. Let's start with 1, 2, 4, 5. 1 must be diagonally across from 4, since otherwise they would create a 5. However, in that case, 4 would be next to 2 and 1 would be next to 5, which would create a pair of sixes.


 What about 1, 2, 3, 6? 1 would have to be diagonally adjacent from 2 to avoid a second 3, but all of the other combinations work. 1+3=4, 1+6=7, 2+3=5, 2+6=8 are all unique.


Correct and well done!

Initial Definition

There are only four possible operations: adding $1$ to each of the cells in the top-left, top-right, bottom-left, and bottom-right regions. Call these four operations $A,B,C,D$ respectively. Note that combining operations is both transitive and associative. I will use addition syntax for combination, and multiplication syntax (between an integer and an operation) for running an operation multiple times.

Constraints

Each of the four corners has only one corresponding operation that increases it. Since all four corner numbers must be different, $A,B,C,D$ must all be applied a different number of times. Let the total transformation of the board be $aA+bB+cC+dD$—that is, operation $A$ was done $a$ times, operation $B$ was done $b$ times, and similarly for the other two. Note that all four of $a,b,c,d$ are different. Now, our matrix is:
\begin{bmatrix}a&a+b&b\\a+c&a+b+c+d&b+d\\c&c+d&d\end{bmatrix}
Note that none of the four values can be zero—else, some values would be equal.

Knowing this, we can find that the center square's number is not of concern—it is clearly greater than all of the other numbers in the matrix. Since we already found that $a,b,c,d$ are different, the corners are also of no concern. In addition, "adjacent" edges (i.e., edges that share a corner) are also unequal.

Therefore, the only other major restrictions are as follows:
Opposite edges should not be equal. That is, $a+b\neq c+d$ and $a+c\neq b+d$. There are many quadruplets $(a,b,c,d)$ that satisfy this.
No edge should equal a corner. That is, $a+b\neq c$, and similarly for the others. This is what sets the more important bounds.

Therefore, this is clearly…

possible!

Optimization

First, assume that $1$ and $2$ are part of the set. If they are opposite (WLoG $a$ and $d$ respectively), than our matrix is as follows:
\begin{bmatrix}1&1+b&b\\1+c&3+b+c&2+b\\c&2+c&2\end{bmatrix}
Clearly, $b,c>2$. Assume $b=3$. ($c=3$ is equivalent.)
\begin{bmatrix}1&4&3\\1+c&6+c&5\\c&2+c&2\end{bmatrix}
Here, $c\geq6$. In fact, $c=6$ works, yielding this matrix:
\begin{bmatrix}1&4&3\\7&12&5\\6&8&2\end{bmatrix}
Here, our sum is $12$.
If $b=4$, $c=5$ is the minimum value. This yields the same sum, so we don't need to check this case.

Now, note that if the minimum value were greater than one, the minimum sum would be at least $2+3+4+5=14$, so we can ignore this.
In fact, $1$ and $2$ must be part of the set for further optimization. If only $1$ were present, the minimum would be $1+3+4+5=13$—still too big!

Now, assume that $1$ and $2$ are adjacent. (WLoG, $a=1,b=2$.) Our matrix is now:
\begin{bmatrix}1&3&2\\1+c&3+c+d&2+d\\c&c+d&d\end{bmatrix}
$c,d$ are greater than $3$ now. Therefore, the minimum possible sum for this case is $1+2+4+5=12$, so this doesn't change anything! We don't even need to check!

Therefore, after all those shortcuts, our final minimum is…

twelve!

One matrix with this minimum is:

\begin{bmatrix}1&4&3\\7&12&5\\6&8&2\end{bmatrix}


Your solution is also correct, but I found the accepted answer easier to follow.

That's fair. I was writing the solution as my exact thought process while solving it—I got sniped halfway through, but I decided to finish it up, anyway, since this was a puzzle I actually understood the general solving direction for.

An easy proof that the minimum number of moves "does-n"'t fall below the value given in correct answers:
Suppose that you were to increment only three of the four possible 2×2 blocks, leaving 0 in the corner cell that does not overlap the other three blocks. Then

the remaining cells in the same row and column of the 0 corner cannot be differentiated because they can be incremented only together. For instance, if we do not increment the upper right block then the upper left and upper center cells are forced equal.

Therefore

the minimum value of any cell is 1,

and then

the total sum of all cells must be at least 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9=45, and each move can increase the sum by only 4.

We can also prove that the answer for the square grid itself, with the minimal number of moves, is unique (up to the usual symmetry operations).
To do this, we assume that the four available 2×2 cells are incremented a,b,c,d times such that

 a+b+c+d=12, a<b<c<d. Equalities are not allowed because each corner must be unique.

Since

1+3+4+5=13>12, we must have a=1,b=2; so c+d=9.

So either

c=3,d=6 and we find we must place a=1, b=2 at opposing corners to avoid generating a second 3. Thus the answer given by others.

Or

c=4,d=5, but we find no additional solutions because this case yields either two 5's or two 6's.


Had similar logic to find the lower bound : center cell is the total number of moves and sum of the 8 other cells is therefore 3 times this value, sum of 1 to 8 is 36, so 36/3=12 is a lower bound, even greater than the 11.25 although it's the same when rounded up

I never considered the rot13(fhz)! That's an interesting way to immediately find a bound!

How many turns?

 12

Why is that?

 



Is it possible to obtain different numbers in each cell?


 Yes, it is:
 -Select one corner 2x2 one time
 -Select a second corner 2x2 two times
 -Select a third corner 2x2 four times
 -Select the fourth corner 2x2 eight times


Bonus: what is the least number of turns needed to achieve this?


 Fifteen turns


There are smaller answers.

While yours is the simplest demonstration that all of the cells can be made to be different (since they are all sums of different numbers of powers of 2) the bonus is for the pattern which requires the smallest number of turns to produce.
